# Android virtual emulator stuck on loading - white/black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created a virtual emulator (Nexus 5X API 29) in Android Studio on a Windows 10 host machine.  When I try to start the emulator it will always appear as a black screen.  When I click on it it becomes white and gives me an error that it's not responding:
[image]

It seems to show some content from the device, so it's doing **something** but the screen never loads.  I did not start my own application, I am merely cold booting the emulator.  I have also tried wiping the data and cold boot again, delete the emulator and remake it as well as create another virtual emulator (Pixel 2 API 29).  Nothing worked, the result is the same every time.

I also closed Docker just in case since I heard it might give problems on a Mac, but I am on Windows 10.  What else could be the issue?

Comment: I'm quite positive that it's because haxm is not installed apparently, which is required to run the emulator.  I tried to install it, but my intel cpu does not support VT-x.  It would seem that I won't be able to run this emulator.  I am looking for an alternative which less strict requirements.  FYI, here is the requirements checklist for haxm: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-Installation-Environment-Check-and-Configurations